# using results from query in subquery returns unexpected results

Tags: mysql, subquery

table contains (pid, player, rank, month, season)

I am trying to create a query that displays each player, which months they played, what their rank was for that month and how many players played that month.

Here is what I am trying

```
SELECT name as Name
     , month as Month
     , rank as Rank
     , (select count(*) from results where month='month') as TotalPlayers 
FROM `results` 
WHERE season=CurrentSeason 
  and name="Player"
```

My subquery is returning results for what would be month 0. How do I get this correct?

Comment: please provide some sample data and desired output

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing, but perhaps this is what you want:

```
SELECT name as Name
     , month as Month
     , rank as Rank
     , TotalPlayers 
FROM `results` r
JOIN (
   SELECT month
        , COUNT(*) as TotalPlayers 
   FROM results
   GROUP BY month
   ) m
ON m.month=r.month
WHERE season=CurrentSeason 
  and name="Player"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery returns results for month 0 because `month` is an integer but `'month'` is a string.  MySQL tries to convert the string to an integer.  Because there are no leading digits, the integer is 0.

Instead, you want to use aliases to distinguish the two references of the table `results`.  That way, you can say that the two are equal to each other.

```
SELECT name as Name,
       month as Month,
       rank as Rank,
       (select count(*) from results r2 where r.month=r2.month) as TotalPlayers 
FROM `results` r
WHERE season=CurrentSeason 
  and name="Player"
```

This structure of a subquery is called a "correlated subquery" because the inner subquery refers to a table in an outer query.